# How to execute custom query and return generic list?

Tags: c#, castle-activerecord, castle

I can only seem to find how to return arrays from my function. Here is my model:

```
[ActiveRecord("incident")]
public class Incident : ActiveRecordBase<Incident>
{
    public Incident() { }

    [PrimaryKey("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Property("name")]
    public int Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'm currently using SimpleQuery however I'm not sure if I should be using HqlBasedQuery instead. Here is my call function:

```
 string query = @"select incident_id from Incident where incident_id = :incident_id";
 SimpleQuery<Incident> q = new SimpleQuery<Incident>(typeof(Incident), query);
 q.SetParameter("incident_id", _incidentId);
 q.SetQueryRange(1);
```

This works but I'd like a generic list of Incident objects.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array of T (`T[]`) implements `IList<T>` so you already *are* getting a generic list of objects:

```
string query = ...
IList<Incident> q = new SimpleQuery<Incident>(typeof(Incident), query).Execute();
```

If you want to add elements to that list, wrap it in another list:

```
IList<Incident> q = new List<Incident>(new SimpleQuery<Incident>(typeof(Incident), query).Execute());
```